# It's the third time he called / has called

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

I'd like to know if there's a specific grammar rule about sentences like "it's the second/third (and so on) time" 
Should I always use present perfect?

Comment: I suspect yes, unless it ***was** the first time he **had** called*, in which case it'd be past perfect. Normally a perfect construction would be appropriate.

Comment: The difference would be only a /z/ between /i/ and /k/ in /'taymi'kɔld/, making it /'taymiz'kɔld/, and the /zk/ cluster would automatically devoice to /sk/, making it /'taymi'skɔld/. That's the sort of cluster that can get by with a lick and a promise -- in the case of phonetics, that means a tongue gesture and otherwise no sound -- the way it does with /ɪfyuvgatə'kar/ , usually pronounced /ɪfyugatə'kar/ _if you got a car_.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the proper grammar is to use the perfect. 'It's the first time he called' I would use the past. I think there's no need to worry about it, Diana. Trust me the majority of people where I live, in Massachusetts, would use the past and wouldn't even give a damn if you told them 'the right way is to use the perfect'. The other problem here is that if you're passing an international English exam  and doing this multiple choice test, that past tense could get you in trouble. But on the whole I'd suggest that you relax about it